# Python: Find constants from mathematical model to reconstruct measured data

Tags: python, scipy, sympy

I try to calculate the constants of a known mathematical model for my measured (and already filtered) data.

A little bit of pseudo code:

```
#my data is saved in y_data and x_data
#my model is a function of constants (a,b,c) and the x_data
model = f(x_data, a, b, c)

#set model equal to data
y_data != model
calculate(a, b, c)
```

Is there any way to find the constants? I know there will be no exact result...but is it possible for a deviation (e.g. 5%) of y_data?

An alternative would be to calculate the constants for each index. Then have len(x_data) equations and somehow find the best fitting model and its constants.

I tried to simplify my issue, furthermore this is my first question, so let me know when I could to something better.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your model linear (e.g. `y=a+b*x[0]+c*x[1]`) or non-linear?

Comment: Unfortunately my model is non-linear.
My measures are frequency responses from electrical elements.

Comment: Okay well then you might need to use numerical optimization.  I'll show you one way to do this with scipy in an answer below.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your fast help!

Answer (score 0):

If your model is linear, the simplest methods would be least squares (linear regression).  There is a nice tutorial with examples [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/05.06-linear-regression.html).

Since it appears your model is non-linear (and assuming you can't or don't want to find an analytical solution), you might want to try [numerical optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization).

Scipy has a function called [`minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) which you could use to try to find the best solution.  But it is not guaranteed to find the global minimum.  So you may have to try different initial conditions.

Your code might look something like this:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# Initial guess
x0 = [1.3, 0.7, 0.8]
res = minimize(cost_function, x0, tol=1e-5)
print(res.x)
```

The trick is, you need to define the function `cost_function` that you give to the solver, first.

It's common to use quadratic errors (sum of squared-errors or mean-squared error).  Something like this:

```
def cost_function(x):
    a, b, c = x
    model_predictions = f(x_data, a, b, c)
    return sum((model_predictions - y_data)**2)
```

You might also have to try different solvers which are built into `scipy.optimize.minimize`.  Refer to the documentation on the pros and cons of each method.

Maybe get familiar with the examples in the Scipy documentation first, then try to set it up on your actual problem.

Comment: Thanks @Bill! 
I will try this out tomorow - keep you informed.